# FindFirstFile LPCSTR

Tags: c++, windows, string, winapi, lpcstr

Hello i got a problem with my code here.

```
LPCSTR mergeString(LPCSTR firstString, std::string secondString)
{
    string convertedString = ConvertString(firstString);
    LPCSTR mergedString;
    int i = convertedString.size();

    convertedString.insert(i, secondString);
    mergedString = (convertedString.c_str());

    return mergedString;
}

void GetFiles(LPCSTR path)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA File_Data; 
    LPCSTR lPath = mergeString(path,"\\*.txt");
    FindFirstFile(lPath, &File_Data);
    wcout << File_Data.cFileName;
}
```

You pass in the path you want to use in the GetFiles(LPCSTR path) Then i use the mergestring function to merge together the path with a extension (\*.txt) everything works except when it returns the LPCSTR then its just a lot of wierd characters and i dont know why or is it a better way to do this?

Comment: This is your main problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Comment: According to [this documentation for the `c_str` method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/), the return value is "only guaranteed to remain unchanged until the next call to a non-constant member function of the string object." Destructing the object counts as a non-constant member function, at which point the value returned by `c_str` is no longer valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is *unnecessarily* complicated.
If you just want to add a `\*.txt` suffix to the input path string, you can simply use `std::string` with its overloaded `operator+`.

Then, if you want to pass a `std::string` to a Win32 API that has a `const char*` (i.e. `LPCSTR`) parameter, you can use `std::string::c_str()` method:

```
void GetFiles(LPCSTR path)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fileData; 
    std::string searchPath(path);
    searchPath += "\\*.txt";

    FindFirstFile(searchPath.c_str(), &fileData);
    wcout << fileData.cFileName;
}
```

Note also that in modern world you should use Unicode (UTF-16) for Win32 programming; so `const wchar_t*` and `std::wstring` are better options than `const char*` and `std::string`.
Moreover, I'd just use a `std::wstring` class as parameter, instead of a raw `wchar_t` pointer.

```
void GetFiles(const std::wstring& path)
{
    std::wstring searchPath = path + L"\\*.txt";
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fileData; 
    FindFirstFile(searchPath.c_str(), &fileData);
    std::wcout << fileData.cFileName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `GetFiles` function is returning a pointer to memory which is no longer valid, `File_Data.cFileName` can only be used in `GetFiles` because that's where `File_Data` is defined. The simplest solution is to use the C++ string class`std::string`.

```
std::string GetFiles(LPCSTR path)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA File_Data; 
    LPCSTR lPath = mergeString(path,"\\*.txt");
    FindFirstFile(lPath, &File_Data);
    return File_Data.cFileName;
}
```

Using pointers unnecessarily is a bad habit to get into, for this kind of reason (any many more).

Your mergeString function should also be rewritten with fewer pointers.

```
std::string mergeString(LPCSTR firstString, std::string secondString)
{
    string convertedString = ConvertString(firstString);
    int i = convertedString.size();

    convertedString.insert(i, secondString);
    return convertedString;
}
```